# Magento goal funnels not registered as exits in Google analytics

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I have a Magento goal set up in Google analytics, but none of the checkout steps are ever registered as exits. Based on the goal funnel report, it seems all users that reach the checkout onepage also reach the success page, which is highly unlikely. I noticed the checkout steps are registered correctly by Google, as I can see for example 200 page views for saveBilling and 140 for savePayment, so I assume the steps are registered.

I have noticed several other posts on this topic but none that would explain this. The destination is set to "Begins with" and the value: "/checkout/onepage/success/" and I have the following goals funnels setup

```
1. /checkout/cart/ (required)
2. ^/checkout/onepage/$
3. ^/checkout/onepage/\?register=
4. ^/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/$
5. ^/checkout/onepage/saveShipping/$
6. ^/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/$
7. ^/checkout/onepage/savePayment/$
8. ^/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/$
9. ^/ops/payment/placeform/
```

I also tried setting the funnels without the starting ^ and the ending $ but still nothing
Does anyone see any reason why no exits would be detected?

EDIT:
After many tries, I concluded it cannot be done. The goal shows all exists under /checkout/onepage step because all subsequent steps contain this url. The solution I used in the end is to create a separate goal with starting step "/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/" and end step "/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/" and this seems to work like a charm. Altough the only difference between the two goals is the initial one also contained cart and onepage as steps, the first doesn't register the exists properly while the other ones does. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the "Regular Expression" option when configuring the destination URI. I've never had luck with "Begins with". I would keep the format consistent across the rest of the goal funnel steps, so if you use RegEx, use it for the rest.

I would try escaping the forward slashes, too.

1. /checkout/cart/
2. /checkout/onepage/
3. /checkout/onepage/.*